# When using $watch(..., true) should the standard $watch be removed?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-watch

As I understand it Angular will automatically setup standard `$watch`'s for any `$scope` defined value within a controller that correlates with a model in the view.

But let's say I want of these values to check for equality instead. So within the controller I'd add a `$watch(..., ..., true)`.

Doesn't that mean that there are now two `$watch`'s running for the same value, each with a different watch depth? And if so, should I remove the standard `$watch` that Angular setup initially in order to remove the redundant `$watch` and thereby increase performance?

Answer (score 0):

No, I think we are just overriding default watch of the angular when we write watch for scope variable , even if we write equality true or false I think this will override default watch of angular